# How to have a script working while doing something else?

Tags: android, macros, autohotkey

My script works flawlessly how I want it to. The problem is I can't do anything else on my computer because of the script that's running. I am using it for a mobile android game, using the app called Nox (Android emulator; the game is clash royal).

So I tried some methods of trying to get the script work in just that window only, so I can browse the internet while its doing its thing in the background.
I can't get it to work. I've tried several methods. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Code is below.

```
Esc::ExitApp

F2::
Suspend
Pause,,1
return

F1::
Random, sleepx, 100, 2540
MouseGetPos, x,y
{
    MouseClick, left,  158,  385
    Sleep, sleepx
    MouseClick, left,  161,  515
    Sleep, sleepx
}
Send, {F1}
return
```

It's a simple left mouse clicking script. It keeps looping over and over, with a random timer between `[100 - 2540]`.

Comment: Why exactly can't you do anything else? Because the mouse keeps jumping around the screen or ...? And what do you use the `x` and `y` coordinates for?

Comment: Tried [ControlClick](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm)?

Comment: The mouse jumps around the screen. Making it too where I have too look at my computer and watch it do its thing without being able too do anything else. I want it too where it plays the script in that Window only so I can do other things while the script is working in the background.   I use the x,y coords for the specific things in the window I have too click too make the script work. Clicking "battle" and "ok" when it's done and it just repeats.. Battle->[Battle ends] -> Okay -> Battle etc..

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotKey's mouseclick function is actually exactly that. A function that clicks the mouse. 
Your mouse.
There is no way for you to use your mouse as you normally would and at the same time automate your mouse movements and actions somewhere else. Windows can only handle one mouse at a time.

I think that what you are looking to do is to send an event that Nox may interpret as a click while not being an actual mouseclick. I have no idea whether Nox supports this, though.